# How to import KML file, with custom data, to Postgres/PostGIS database?

Tags: postgis, kml, ogr2ogr

By custom, I don't mean a different structure of KML file, but in `<description></description>` section, I have data with HTML tags of this kind:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document>
<Placemark>
  <name>New York City</name>
  <description><![CDATA[
    <table>
      <tr><td colspan='2'>Attributes</td></tr>
      <tr><td>CITY_ID</td><td>150335</td></tr>
      <tr><td>POPULATION</td><td>8244910</td></tr>
      <tr><td>AREA</td><td>468.48</td></tr>
    </table>]]>
  </description>
  <Point>
    <coordinates>40.712964,-74.003886,0</coordinates>
  </Point>
</Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

I want to easily import all this data, for each placemark, to a table with corresponding columns in the database, how to do this?

Comment: There are many ways to accomplish this. Can you tell us more about what tools you are familiar with? Are you looking for a programming-oriented solution (what language do you like?) or a tool-based solution (e.g., ArgGIS, QGIS)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you can use ST_GeomFromKML as this [page](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_GeomFromKML.html).

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromKML('
        <LineString>
            <coordinates>-71.1663,42.2614 
                -71.1667,42.2616</coordinates>
        </LineString>');
```

or you can use ogr2ogr as following to process entire KML files;

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=yourhost user=youruser dbname=yourdb 
                            password=yourpass" inputfilename.kml
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: ogr2ogr: you're saying go from KML to SHP then to PG. Why he can't use from KML to PG with one step?

Comment: It works! and for reference, I want to add some comments: I've found ogr2ogr in /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs/ (on a Mac) and there's warnings if content of <description> section contains more than 80 caracters.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For those happier in QGIS, drag your KML file to QGIS. Then connect to your Postgres database as documented [here](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/databases/db_manager.html#basic-fa-managing-postgis-databases-with-db-manager) then add the layers your want from QGIS as new table in your schema

Comment: That's what I would do!

Answer (score 0):

I have used this command in the shell to import a KML file into a PostgreSQL database and it has worked perfectly for me. I share my solution.

```bsh
ogr2ogr --config PG_USE_COPY YES -f PGDump /vsistdout/ filename.kml | psql db_name db_user
```