# Data missing while importing .kml file to PostgreSQL using ogr2ogr

Tags: postgis, kml, ogr2ogr

As I am newbie to both dealing with KML and PostgreSQL. 
I am able to load KML file to PostgreSQL. But feature data table is empty. My file structure is same as mentioned in link. 
while importing .kml file, it has asked to create schema and table. So after creating both, KML table has some data. but placemark data table is empty.

I took help from this link 
[How to import KML file, with custom data, to Postgres/PostGIS database?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33102/how-to-import-kml-file-with-custom-data-to-postgres-postgis-database/33115).

Is there a way to see placemark data as a table view?